# Finding all possible bijections between two sets

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, permutation

what I want to do is to create an algorithm, able to find all the possible bijections between two sets of objects.

A simple example, let's suppose we have two arrays {1,2,3} {4,5,6}.

The algorithm should give me 3!= 3*2*1 =6 bijections which are the following:

1-4   2-5  3-6 \
1-4   2-6  3-5\
1-5   2-4  3-6\
1-5   2-6  3-4\
1-6   2-5  3-4 \
1-6   2-4  3-5\

Even though it seems simple at first place, I am quite stuck. Is there any standard algorithm in the theory of combinatorics, bijections or permutations to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Christina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it **recursively**, "choose" one variable from each - and add it to the solution - do it for all possibilities, and narrow your possible choices at each recursive call.

Pseudo code should be something like [assuming |S1| == |S2|]:

```
getAllBijections(S1,S2,sol):
   if (S1 is empty):
       print sol
   else:
       first <- S1.first
       S1 <- S1.deleteFirst()
       for each e in S2:
           S2.remove(e)
           sol.append(first,e)
           getAllBijections(S1,S2,sol) // note we are invoking with modified S1,S2,sol
           sol.removeLast() //remove the last sol
           S2.add(e) //return e to S2
       end for
   end if
```

Note that **it indeed generate `n!` possibilities**, because for each iteration you have one less element to choose from, resulting in total of `n * (n-1) * ... * 1 = n!` possibilities, as expected..

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any standard algorithm in the theory of combinatorics, bijections or permutations to solve this problem?

**Yes!** Generating all bijections between two sets of N elements is the same as *generating all permutations* of N elements; think of the permutation as indicating, for each element of the first set, which element of the second set will be the image under the bijection.  Thus you are looking for an algorithm to "generate all permutations".

Knuth has a short [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201853930) on the subject, which you can also download for free: "[The Art of Computer Programming: Generating all Permutations](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/fasc2b.ps.gz)" (note: compressed postscript format).  The first algorithm he gives is "Algorithm L", an interesting alternative to the obvious recursive algorithms.

The wikipedia discussion of "[Algorithms to generate permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations)" will be of interest to you.  If you are programming in C++, you could use the implementation in the [`next_permutation`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) function.

(Of course, this assumes you are talking about *countable* sets, and not, say, bijections of the real numbers, like `x ⟼ x+1`.)

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write "finite" and not "countable"?

Comment: I think it's possible to list the permutations of an infinite, countable set like the integers.

Comment: If you can list an uncountable set, yes: [An easy proof of the uncountability of bijections on natural numbers?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29475/an-easy-proof-of-the-uncountability-of-bijections-on-natural-numbers)

Comment: There is a nicer and countable set: the set of permutations that fix all but finitely many elements.

Answer (score 2):

A way to simplify this problem is to simply take all permutations of the second array, and then perform an n-to-n mapping between the first array and each permuted second array.

For example, if you have [1,2] and [3,4], first compute the permutations of [3,4] -> {[3,4],[4,3]}, and then pair each to [1,2].  The result is {[(1,3),(2,4)],[(1,4),(2,3)]}.

I've included an example implementation in Python, below.

```
import itertools
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]

for p in itertools.permutations(b):
    print zip(a,p)

# Output:
# [(1, 3), (2, 4)]
# [(1, 4), (2, 3)]
```